# Reasons for MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, sms

The documentation for `MFMessageComposeViewController` says you should check `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` before trying to create a `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

It also says:

> in iOS 5.0 or later, you should register as an observer of the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification` notification to be notified of changes in the availability of sending text messages.

**What possible reasons could there be for the availability of text messaging changing?**
Is it just to [make Linus Torvalds cry](https://twitter.com/ceterum_censeo/status/157059948566679552)?

Background: I’m creating an iOS app that requires the ability to send SMS messages. I’ve added `sms` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in `Info.plist`. It should only run on iPhones (according to Apple docs, I read somewhere this **does not** include iPod touches or iPads solely with iMessage)

If text messaging is not available, the app is useless, and should present some useful error message.

**Update:** I’ve tested with my iPhone 4S that simply having a locked SIM still returns YES from `canSendText` – still not a reason for message sending ability to change.

**Update #2**: I have created a [simple test app](https://github.com/DouglasHeriot/CanSendText) to see what might cause it. **I have not received the notification at all.**

Things that don’t cause MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification

- Turning iMessage on & off
- Losing WiFi connectivity
- Turning on airplane mode
- Locking iPhone SIM card

Things that can cause canSendText to change between YES/NO (but not send a notification)

- Turning iMessage on & off on an iPad (I assume iPod touch too)

I’m guessing the correct case is for iPads and iPod touches when iMessage is turned on or off, however, there must be a bug (either in my test code or Apple’s) that’s preventing this from working.

If you need this notification, I tried just checking `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` again on `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. This sometimes works, but if you switch quickly between Settings.app and your app, it may not have changed yet by the time you switch to your app, causing `canSendText` to still reflect the old value.

My solution for now is just going to be simply checking `canSendText` just before relevant decisions are made, and handle the (rare?) case where it may have changed without me knowing in some appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is **no case** where `MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification` is sent.

The only time when the value of `canSendText` changes is when iMessage is turned on/off on an iPad or iPod Touch (not an iPhone, which has SMS messaging).

**Even when `canSendText` changes, no notification is sent.**
(Unless it’s just a bug in my [test code](https://github.com/DouglasHeriot/CanSendText)?) This appears to be a bug or missing feature in Apple’s code.

Answer (score 2):

Since `MFMessageComposeViewController` can use iMessage in iOS5, I'm guessing it's probably to handle the case where iPod Touches and Wi-fi iPads lose internet connectivity while a message is being typed.

Comment: That’s a good idea – I’ll make sure I test this next time I’ve got access to an iPod Touch.

Comment: Another thought – it could be when iMessage is turned on and off on an iPod Touch?

Comment: You should be able to test this case on your iPhone by turning on airplane mode, then turning Wifi back on and walking out of range of your wifi hotspot.

Yeah, it should also handle the case of someone changing their iMessage status.

Comment: See my question Update #2 above – I marked your answer as correct, but it’s **not actually correct** – I haven’t been able to receive a MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification ever at all, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to rule out another scenario where it does not trigger `MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification`.

- Sender iPad with a working wifi connection
- Reciepient Android phone

Result: `MessageComposeResult == MessageComposeResultSent`, `MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification` was not triggered

Next I tried the same scenario with iMessage in order to duplicate the final results. (== not being able to send an iMessage).

Then I realized that iMessage was able to tell me **in advance** this would never work by putting a red exclamation next to the recipients name with the message this person is not registered with iMessage. The `MFMessageComposeViewController` does not do this!!!

My current conclusion is: `canSendText` should be named **canComposeText**.
`MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification` does nothing.

Comment: That’s interesting the `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn’t warn you at all, while Messages.app does. Especially for iPad/iPods, that’s a pretty bad bug! – basically makes it totally un-useable for iPads/iPods, as users would be way too confused. Definitely something you/I should report to Apple.

I also noticed on iPhone it always shows phone numbers and the send button as blue, while Messages.app will switch to green when SMS messages are used.